# how to change document.body.style.margin in cordova/phonegap

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

The following code works in Firefox outside of Cordova. But inside Cordova it does not. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/fxECFiZ.gifv) is an gif of the two side by side.

Why is document.body.style.margin not updating?

```
var style = document.body.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
if(xMove === -1 && yMove === 0)
  document.body.style.marginTop = parseInt(style.marginTop, 10) - 60;
if(xMove === 0 && yMove === -1)
  document.body.style.marginLeft = parseInt(style.marginLeft, 10) - 60; 
if(xMove === 1 && yMove === 0)
  document.body.style.marginTop = parseInt(style.marginTop, 10) + 60;
if(xMove === 0 && yMove === 1)
  document.body.style.marginLeft = parseInt(style.marginLeft, 10) + 60;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered. Chrome and firefox don't care about the px, but cordova does!

```
document.body.style.marginTop = (parseInt(style.marginTop, 10) - 60) + 'px';
```